# What does "why yes" mean?

Tags: idiom-meaning

In this chat on github I found:

A. I made some changes. Please review.

B. Awesome, thanks!

A. Why yes, of course

What A means in his last sentence?

In general, is "why yes" a stronger "yes"?

Comment: Note that for this use of *why* as an interjection there would normally be a comma directly after *why* (as in deadrat's examples below).

Answer (score 15):

*Why* here is an interjection, placed at the beginning of a sentence to express surprise:

> Is it nine o'clock already?  Why, I must have fallen asleep!

or opposition:

> Are you suggesting he stole the money?  Why, I think that's
>   impossible.

or in you example, emphasis:

> B. Awesome, thanks!
>  A. Why [would you think it would be any less
>   than awesome?], yes of course.

or perhaps

> A. Why [would I even need to be thanked for something I'm happy to
>   do], yes, of course.

Don't take the bracketed words as a literal ellipsis.  The *why* is there to express a general emphatic tone.

The *OED* finds the interjectory use of *why* going back five hundred years.

Answer (score 1):

I speak Persian. And in Persian, we use the word why by itself as a synonym for yes in some situations, usually for emphasis. As the answer above suggested, it probably is the shortened form of "why not?" in both languages.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. It's interesting to learn that this form exists in Persian. This would be a more interesting and useful post for this site, however, if you could provide etymological source material to back up your theory about "why yes" might be a shortened form of "why not" in English. We try to provide information about English usage, rather than opinion. (I'd actually disagree that "why yes" is a shortened form of "why not" in English. It could, in a pinch, be a variant). Your observation about Persian is different and interesting, because you are, as a speaker, a source yourself.

Comment: You are correct that it was just an observation. But I was not trying to suggest "why not?" was a replacement for "why, yes", rather that it was a replacement for why alone- as in "why not? Yes, of course". However, you are absolutely right about providing a source. But I think the phrasing of the comment above mine basically suggests the same idea as "why not?"

Answer (score -1):

The statement above, "Why yes, of course," seems practically redundant.  "Why yes" seems to me (yes, I know, no sources) to mean "why would I have it any other way" or "why would I want to do otherwise."  And that seems very close to the meaning of "of course" in the sentence -- the etymology of which I do not know but would suspect to mean "of the course I would expect" or "of the natural or defined or common course."  So the meanings of the two phrases seem very close.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/411222)