# Use of "why" in spoken conversation

Tags: expressions

What's the exact term used to describe the "why" in some people's spoken English (somewhat rural or archaic by now, I suppose) as in "When I saw how much it cost, why, I knew I couldn't afford it".....or "When our family car broke down, why, we'd just walk, until we could fix it", etc....anybody recognize these? If so, why the "why"?

Comment: Related question: [What does "why yes" mean?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/280621/what-does-why-yes-mean)

Answer (score 4):

"Why" is an old fashioned interjection, which is used when you are surprised or have suddenly realized something:
For example:
*Why, look who's here!*
*And I thought to myself, why, I can do that.*

Definition from the Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English 
Advanced Learner's Dictionary. http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/why_2